# Is there any way to send different data packets together over wireline/wireless link?

Tags: routing, protocol-theory, networking, bandwidth, link-utilization

I would like to know if there is a technology that allow to send many packets (of different data) together and at the same time over communication link (whether in wireline or wireless networks) of course by respecting the MTU ?

Comment: The point of packets is that they are sent one at a time, routed one at a time, and each could take a different path.

Comment: That is called a  communication link...